# React Native , bundleReleaseJsANdAssets error?

Tags: react-native

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
> Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:

- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':lottie-react-native:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':lottie-react-native:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':lottie-react-native:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':lottie-react-native:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'project Directoy\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please
  refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-firebase_app:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-firebase_app:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-firebase_storage:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-firebase_storage:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-firebase_storage:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer
  to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-gesture-handler:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-gesture-handler:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer
  to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-gesture-handler:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-google-signin_google-signin:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please
  refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-google-signin_google-signin:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-google-signin_google-signin:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-google-signin_google-signin:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-linear-gradient:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-linear-gradient:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-linear-gradient:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer
  to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-linear-gradient:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-masked-view_masked-view:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-masked-view_masked-view:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-masked-view_masked-view:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-masked-view_masked-view:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit
  or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
  ed a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-safe-area-context:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-safe-area-context:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-screens:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-screens:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-screens:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-screens:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-vector-icons:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-vector-icons:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-vector-icons:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to
  for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\BTSoftwares\MahakalMobileApp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-vector-icons:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to  for more details about this problem.
  warning: the transform cache was reset.

React Native unexpected Error.